# Calculate the minimum absolute difference between the maximum and minimum number from the triplet of 3 arrays

Tags: algorithms, arrays

Question is:

*Calculate the minimum absolute difference between the maximum and minimum number from the triplet a, b, c such that a, b, c belongs arrays A, B, C respectively.*

There is another question: *Find i, j, k such that :
`max(abs(A[i] - B[j]), abs(B[j] - C[k]), abs(C[k] - A[i]))` is minimized.
Return the minimum max(abs(A[i] - B[j]), abs(B[j] - C[k]), abs(C[k] - A[i])). A, B & C are sorted arrays.*

Reading the solution approach [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-three-closest-elements-from-given-three-sorted-arrays/) and [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/smallest-difference-triplet-from-three-arrays/), I realize that the solution approach for both these questions is same, to:

```
minimize abs( max(a,b,c) - min(a,b,c) )
```

I'm not sure why this follows and how we should go about relating these two questions and their algorithms. Why are these two questions identical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you see the following equality?
 abs( max(a,b,c) - min(a,b,c) ) = max(abs(a - b), abs(b - c), abs(c - a))

Here is a hint to prove the equality.

> Without loss of generality, we can assume a >= b >= c.

By the way, the first abs is not necessary since max(a, b, c) is always no less than min (a, b, c).